# PayPal tls 1.2 SSL Update 10002

Tags: .net, paypal, webforms, tls1.2

I'm just testing my web site to make sure that its compatible to the new tls 1.2 etc. 
I;m getting the 10002  You do not have permissions to make this API call error
When using my test sandbox system.

Does this mean i can contact paypal and it will all be fine any way?

I'm using .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose yes, the TLS connection is successful if you received the API response back from PayPal even with an error. PayPal has completed TLS 1.2 upgrade in sandbox environment so you can prepare for the live upgrade in near future. More information on the TLS 1.2 upgrade: https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait on some other opinions and I'll set yours as an answer :).

Comment: No problem. I am glad to help!

Comment: What is weird that I get the SSL error when I run it locally but, when i run it off the live app on the server it gets the API error above.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in .NET, but based on my understanding, it could be due to the .NET framework version. You need to make sure .NET framework 4.5 and above installed in your localhost